# Why its not giving me the correct total month?

Tags: javascript

Why it's not giving me the correct total month? (with compared to current `mm-yyyy`)

```
function get_total_month(mm,yyyy) {
  // custom inputs
  var start_date = new Date(yyyy, mm, 01); 

  // current date
  var today_date = new Date();
  var today_year = today_date.getFullYear();
  var today_month = today_date.getMonth();
  var today_day = today_date.getDate();    
  var end_date = new Date(new Date(today_year, today_month, today_day));

  // compare the given date with current date to find the total months
  var total_months = (end_date.getFullYear() - start_date.getFullYear())*12 + (end_date.getMonth() - start_date.getMonth());

  return total_months;
}

alert(    
  get_total_month(01, 2014)    
);
```

Giving me: **20** instead of **22**

Comment: “Total month”? Can you explain in detail what this function is supposed to do?

Comment: `new Date(new Date(...))`??? That makes no sense

Comment: `getMonth()` returns 0 thru 11. In any case, given it's October (and you appear to be using one-based months), `(2015-2014)*12+(10-1)` would give **21 !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the [`Date.prototype.getMonth`](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/date/getmonth) method returns a 0-11 number. So:

```
January = 0
February = 1
...
December = 11
```

Comment: So your answer is this code: copy paste version: https://jsfiddle.net/b1prajwm/1/

Comment: is it +2 or +1. is it 22 months or 21 months?

Comment: In fact, it's +1, because firstly you must subtract the values, and then, add 1 month to the result. So, it's 21 :)

Comment: OK -  but if you input: "10-2015" the result is giving 0, which is not correct, in my application requirement it has to say 1 month remaining for to buy tickets. i cant say 0 months remaining to buy your promo ticket. should it not be then 22 in my case?

Comment: @YumYumYum yeah, it should :)

Comment: Oh god, so simple but it still confuse me. thanks a lot. for me i needed 22 so +2 i used.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for, it is another version of your code. But I think is shorter and easier to understand. What do you think?

(I added the +2 to adjust the result to what you are expecting the function to return)

```js
 function monthDifference(startDate) {
        var months;
        var currentDate = new Date();
        months = (currentDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()) * 12;
    
        months -= startDate.getMonth() + 1;
        months += currentDate.getMonth();
        return months <= 0 ? 0 : (months + 2);
    }
    
    alert(monthDifference(new Date(2014,0)) );
    alert(monthDifference(new Date(2013,11)) );
```